# Nullspace with square root values.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

So I am trying to find the eigenvector for $\lambda=2+\sqrt{2}$ for the matrix $$A=\begin{bmatrix} 3 &1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}$$ and after trying to find the null space I got  $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 &0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$$ but my prof said it was supposed to be  $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1-\sqrt{2}\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$$ and I've tried it over multiple and multiple times and I keep getting the same matrix. So am I just doing something wrong or is my prof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$|\lambda I-A|=\begin{vmatrix}\lambda-3&-1\\-1&\lambda-1\end{vmatrix}$$

Now substitute $\;\lambda=2+\sqrt2\;$ and solve the resulting linear system:

$$\begin{cases}&(-1+\sqrt2)x-y=0\\&-x+(1+\sqrt2)y=0\end{cases}\implies x=(1+\sqrt2)y$$

and thus, for example, the following is an eigenvector for this eigenvalue:

$$\binom{1+\sqrt2}1$$

Comment: Oh geez I feel stupid. Was forgetting to add in this value.. Oops. Thanks